# Ubuntu 12.04 full iphone backup

Tags: ubuntu, backup, itunes, iphone, wine

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and have an iPhone 5 using iOS 6.0.2. My question is how can I do a full backup on Ubuntu. Most questions I have seen on this are related to peoples music libraries etc how ever this is of little importance to me. What I want to be able to do is a complete (photos,contacts, OS etc) image backup (and restore if required).

So far I have looked up `libimobiledevice` and this seems to be just that a API.  Other suggestions are about **Rhythmbox** for music etc but this is not of huge importance to me. Finally the suggestion is for using **iTunes** and some combination of **Wine** or **Playforlinux**. But even if you get iTunes working iPhone access is limited.

Surely someone must have the same problem and found a solution.